# How can I disable the cache via the database?

Tags: cache, database, development, debugging

I have an automated job which converts our production database backups into development-friendly databases.  I'd like to include the disabling of Magento's cache in this job as well, but haven't found where it would be configured.

I've looked in `core_config_data` but didn't see any relevant records.  What tables and records would I need to update to be equivalent to `System > Cache Management > Select All [check-boxes] > Actions = Disable > Submit`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of the cache information is stored inside a table named `core_cache_option`.

If you browse to this table you will see that it contains a code and a value; the code being the type of cache and the value being a `0 or 1` representing off or on. Simply change the values based upon your needs.

Answer (score 1):

this will be the query

```
UPDATE `core_cache_option` SET `value`='0' WHERE 
`code`='translate';
```